# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I receive this error in the following code: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot'.

my code gives an error. I am trying to first query a list of users (that are in a collection) from Firestore than use the data to query from an other collection. It seems like I am making an error while updating the list which could be caused by a mistake in query part.

```js
const dailyTaskFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * *").timeZone("GMT +3").onRun(async () => { 
        
    const users = await db.collection("users").where("location", "==", "GMT+3").get();
    const taskPromises = users.docs.map((doc) => {
        return db
          .collection("tasks")
          .where("dailyTasks", "==", true)
          .where("completed", "==", true)
          .where("userID", "==", doc.get("userID"))
          .get();
    });
    const taskDocs = await Promise.all(taskPromises);
    const actionsPromises = taskDocs.map((snapshot) => {
        return db.collection("tasks").doc(snapshot.id).set({ completed: false }, { merge: true });
    });
    await Promise.all(actionsPromises);
    return null;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) class, doesn't contain any `id` property. However, [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) does. According to the docs, the [id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#id) is of type string and provides the document's ID. This means that you need to loop through the `snapshot` object using [forEach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#foreach) to get its children that are of type `QueryDocumentSnapshot`. Now, you can simply use the `id` property for each and every document and use it further in your referece.

Comment: It would really help if you could share the code

Comment: You should make your own attempt given the information in my answer and ask another question if something else comes up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the query snapshots returned to your variable taskDocs, so you can get a QueryDocumentSnapshot for each item, then you can get the id.

```
const dailyTaskFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('0 0 * * *')
  .timeZone('GMT +3')
  .onRun(async () => {
    const users = await db
      .collection('users')
      .where('location', '==', 'GMT+3')
      .get()
    const taskPromises = users.docs.map((doc) => {
      return db
        .collection('tasks')
        .where('dailyTasks', '==', true)
        .where('completed', '==', true)
        .where('userID', '==', doc.get('userID'))
        .get()
    })
    const taskDocs = await Promise.all(taskPromises)
    const actionsPromises = taskDocs.map((snapshots) => {
      return snapshots.docs.map((snapshot) => {
        return db
          .collection('tasks')
          .doc(snapshot.id)
          .set({ completed: false }, { merge: true })
      })
    })
    await Promise.all(actionsPromises)
    return null
  })
```

Comment: I receive this error: Property 'docs' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>[]'

Comment: Edited to reflect

Comment: there are no errors but code is not working

Comment: You need to provide more details, whats not working?

Comment: In VSCode there are no errors but when I run the code it is not updating the fields it should.

Answer (score 0):

`taskDocs` is an array of QuerySnapshot. You need to run loop on each document in each QuerySnapshot inside them. Those DocumentSnapshots will have the document ID:

```js
    const actionsPromises = []
    
    taskDocs.forEach((userTasksDocs) => {
      userTasksDocs.docs.forEach((taskDoc) => {
        actionsPromises.push(
          db
            .collection('tasks')
            .doc(taskDoc.id)
            .set({ completed: false }, { merge: true })
        );
      });
    });
```